# Icon not visible when .jar file is run but visible through IDE

Tags: java, swing, jar, icons, embedded-resource

So I have created a GUI application, I have set the image for each frame using this:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("./Icons/icon32x32.png");
                frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
                frame.setVisible(true);
```

When I run it through Eclipse, the image is being displayed successfully, but when I export the project to a .jar file it doesn't.

I have tried running the jar in both "double click" fashion and by using CMD

```
java -jar jarfilename.jar
```

Comment: is the icon inside the jar?

Comment: When exporting as a jar, it'll search for the image in `Icons/icon32x32.png`. Chances are that that's not where the image is when exported. You should package the image as a resource instead and reference it that way to ensure it'll work even when you export.

Comment: Application resources will become **embedded resources** by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.